# How to save CheckBoxRowSelect in Devexpress GridView to class object

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I've simple class called "Order".

```
class Order { 
     public string ID { get;set;} 
     public string Something {get;set;} 
     .... more fields...
}
```

I then assign list of orders into DataSource of GridControl.

```
List <Order> ListOfOrders = new Order();
gridControl.DataSource = ListOfOrders;
```

I've added a CheckBoxRowSelect option in GUI so that user can choose rows by selecting the checkbox. What value do I need to add to `class Order` so that any checkbox change in that `GridControl` gets updated in instant in it's own field so that the `ListOfOrders` is always up to date and has that checkbox value stored so it can be processed?

I've made similar thing with `ComboBox` inside one of the columns and it seems to work instantly without any additional change on my part.

```
  var columnKurier = view.Columns.AddField("Courier");
  columnKurier.ColumnEdit = riCombo;
  columnKurier.VisibleIndex = 0;
  columnKurier.OptionsColumn.AllowFocus = true;
```

I simply had to add `Courier` field into `Order` class and that's it. But i don't know which "field name" should it be for checkbox and whether it will get the same behaviour as for the `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your object order :

```
public Boolean Mark{get;set;}
```

and in your your form contructor  :

```
  InitializeComponent();
        new GridCheckMarksSelection(gridControl);
```

i have atach a class  GridCheckMarksSelection you must add it in your project.

[MarkClass](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/c17053370bbfdecd2f438be561dd31c920160426171430/5f8cfe9a15bd356fbc24778990aafc2820160426171430/51dd90)

I hop that you want

Comment: Isn't there an easier way then some big MarkClass you sent? I already have CheckBox in the Gridcontrol ?

Comment: sorry I did not find an other way ,I work with it with datatable ,Try it it work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can not add the option `CheckBoxRowSelect` to `GridControl`, and just use a `bool` field in your `Class` Order, it should be displayed as checkbox in `GridControl`.

Comment: It's displayed as CheckBox but I want that value to be stored in my Class with all other fields. Sounds reasonable ? If not ? Why not?

Comment: you use option : gridView1.OptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode = GridMultiSelectMode.CheckBoxRowSelect; or just bool field in Class ?